# How to get the node value by passing type in XDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, linq-to-xml

I have below XML.

```
<subscription>
    <subscription_add_ons type="array">
        <subscription_add_on>
            <add_on_code>premium_support</add_on_code>
            <name>Premium Support</name>
            <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
            <unit_amount_in_cents type="integer">15000</unit_amount_in_cents>
            <add_on_type>fixed</add_on_type>
            <usage_percentage nil="true"></usage_percentage>
            <measured_unit_id nil="true"></measured_unit_id>
        </subscription_add_on>
    </subscription_add_ons>
```

My XMLParse function

```
public XNode GetXmlNodes(XElement xml, string elementName)
    {
       List<string> addOnCodes= new List<string>();
       //elementName = "subscription_add_ons ";
        var addOns = xml.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.Parent.Name == elementName).FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (XNode addOn in addOns)
        {
             //Needed to do something like this
            /*var len =  "add_on_code".Length + 2;
            var sIndex = addOn.ToString().IndexOf("<add_on_code>") + len;
            var eIndex = addOn.ToString().IndexOf("</add_on_code>");
            var addOnCode = addOn.ToString().Substring(sIndex, (eIndex - sIndex)).Trim().ToLower();
            addOnCodes.Add(addOnCode);*/
        }
```

As mentioned in comments by @JonSkeet, I updated my snippet as below.

```
  var addOns = xml.Descendants(elementName).Single().Elements();  

  foreach (XNode addOn in addOns)
        {
            /*addon = {<subscription_add_on>
            <add_on_code>premium_support</add_on_code>
            <name>Premium Support</name>
            <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
            <unit_amount_in_cents type="integer">15000</unit_amount_in_cents>
            <add_on_type>fixed</add_on_type>
            <usage_percentage nil="true"></usage_percentage>
            <measured_unit_id nil="true"></measured_unit_id>
        </subscription_add_on>} */
         //how to get the addOnCode node value ?
            var addOnCode = string.Empty;
            addOnCodes.Add(addOnCode);
        }
```

But what I need is from the passed XML, get all the nodes of type `subscription_add_on` then get the value contained in `add_on_code` & add it to string collection.

Or in general get the value of node by passing type ? Tried with the available methods coming from VS Intellisense but not getting the exact method that can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what's happening now? (The commented out code can definitely be improved, but I assume you're starting by trying to get the right elements.) I'd expect that to be a case of finding the `<subscription_add_ons>` element, then just finding the child elements, e.g. `var addOns = xml.Descendants(elementName).Single().Elements();`

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks, in the above XML, can you please clarify to me what is Node & Element ? Because I tried with your snippets it is retruning elements while mine was returning nodes?

Comment: Elements are nodes, but a more specific kind of node. (They're not attributes, or text nodes for example.) That makes them easier to work with, because there's more functionality on `XElement` than on `XNode`. If you're very new to XML in general, I'd recommend reading an XML primer before starting to try to work with them in code.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Thanks! Googling gave me the below pdf. I would surely check this http://www.w3c.it/education/2012/upra/documents/xmlprimer.pdf

Comment: @JonSkeet, can you please check the updated snippet in the post. And suggest me how can I find the node value now ? Thanks!

Comment: You'd use `XElement addOn` instead of `XNode addOn`, and then you could ask for individual elements, e.g. `string code = (string) addOn.Element("add_on_code");`. Once you've read up about XML in general, I'd suggest the LINQ to XML tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution with Xml Linq (XDOCUMENT) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication107
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("subscription_add_on").Select(x => new
            {
                add_on_code = (string)x.Element("add_on_code"),
                name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                quantity = (int)x.Element("quantity"),
                amount = (int)x.Element("unit_amount_in_cents"),
                add_on_type = (string)x.Element("add_on_type")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }


}
```